# Need a "button" type element with an x at the top right that lets me delete the element itself. What am I looking for?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I know this question sounds odd. Perhaps a button is not the element I'm looking for. What I want to to do is have an element that looks like what I have here: 
[image]

Now this is technically a button. However, I'd like a small x to pop up in the top right corner when I hover this element so that I can delete the element itself. I have a feel a button is not the way to go here, but I do need an element with an onClick event.
Any pointers would be much appreciated

Comment: _"Now this is technically a button."_ - does it have any actual button functionality? Or is it _just_ used to display that URL value? If it doesn't "do" anything, then it should certainly _not_ be a button.

Comment: What defines a button in HTML is not its looks, but its functionality. Having `hover`, `focus`, `active` and `focus-visible` states, and firing form submission on click when placed in a `<form>`. If it's an HTMLButtonElement, it does all the above out of the box. Why don't you show us some code?

Comment: One of the reasons people use Bootstrap for is because it's compliant with accessibility standards. To keep that compliance, you should not place a button inside another button which, essentially, is what you're asking for.
The standard for your use-case is to use a ButtonGroup (also called SplitButton) and have two separate buttons.

Comment: @CBroe well, on click renders a component that displays the contents of the RSS feed that the link points to. so it does do something.

Comment: @tao dropdown buttons are exactly what I was looking for and a cleaner solution. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can set an onClick event on any HTML elements. You would probably want to add a separate element with the 'x' and listen for a click on there.

Answer (score 0):

We can certainly have a button element, add a span element inside (to show x), and only show that span on hover with some javascript, and styling it with css:

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
var close = document.querySelector('.close');

btn.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  close.style.display = 'block';

});

btn.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
  close.style.display = 'none';

});

function closeIt(e) {
    btn.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #0f111d;
}

.btn {
  background-color: #50c4e5;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 400px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.close {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  right: 1%;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<button class="btn" onclick="alert('button clicked')"><span onclick="event.stopPropagation();closeIt()" class="close">&times;</span>https://www.pdga.com/frontpage/feed</button>
```

Comment: You're also firing the button's click when closing it. You might want to `stopPropagation()` and prevent it. And if you think that's not necessary, because by the time the event should fire on the button, it has already been removed, you're right. But the entire chain of parents up to window or the first element to `preventPropagation()` is still triggered.